# laravel8 container tag and tagged not working

Tags: laravel, containers

when I try to use tag ,
`app()->tagged('Ts')`  return empty array().
TR and TD implement the same Interface.
code as below,anyone can help?

```
$this->app->bind('TR', function ($app) {
            return new TR();
        });
        $this->app->bind('TD', function ($app) {
            return new TD();
        });

        $this->app->tag(['TR','TB'],'Ts');
```

Answer (score 0):

My code worked after I ran this:

```
composer update
```